# Определить, что является предложением

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, смысл, выбор

Помогите, пожалуйста,  определить, что является предложением:

1. Как красиво озеро в горах!
2. Душистые розы.

Comment: Хотите — определите, не хотите — не надо. Это уж вам решать. Сплошные вопросы: этот и про озеро странный вопрос. :))

Answer (score 1):

1. ***Как красиво озеро в горах!***

[Из словаря](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA&all=x): **КАК. I.** ***местоим. нареч.*** <...> **3.** (в восклиц. с дат. сущ. и инф.). Употр. для выражения **высокой степени** какого-л. состояния, признака, чувства; в высокой степени. *Как я рад тебя видеть!* ***Как красиво в лесу***!

Это восклицательное двусоставное **предложение.** Грамматическая основа: **озеро красиво**, сказуемое составное именное, связка  в форме наст. времени пропущена.

2. ***Душистые розы***. Это **словосочетание** с назывным значением (предмет + его определение). Словосочетания обычно входят в состав какого-то предложения, но могут выполнять **и другие функции:**

назывное (номинативное) предложение: *На столе ваза с цветами. Душистые рОзы...*

номинатив в препозиции: *Душистые рОзы! Как много воспоминаний связано с ними.*

двусоставное предложение с инверсией и переносом ударения: *На столе букет свежих цветов. ДушИстые розы!*

название рассказа: *Душистые розы*

**Примечание.** При наличии **точки** словосочетание "Душистые розы" мы можем рассматривать как **назывное предложение**. Но в таком случае возможен следующий ответ: **оба варианта являются предложениями**. Соответственно, появляется вопрос к составителям данного упражнения.